# How to insert name of image from folder in database (name to be the same)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to have the same name of image in database and in the image folder one I move. In folder is work but in database don't have ideas, can someone help me! Thanks

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {


        request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
            'fullname'=>'required',
            'birthday'=>'required',
            'country'=>'required',
            'address'=>'required|min:10',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ]);


        $image = $request -> file('image');
        $destination = base_path().'/public/img';
        $file_name = rand(100,1).date('h-i-s');
        $image->move($destination, $file_name.".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension());



        $data = $request->all();

        // dd($image);

        $check = $this->create($data);

        return Redirect::to("login")->withSuccess('Great! You have Successfully loggedin');
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the standard code templates?

Comment: set  $data['image'] = $file_name.".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your image name to your db record.

Pass it to your $data before calling create method.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {

        ....

        $data = $request->all();

        $data['imageName'] = $file_name.".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $check = $this->create($data);

        return Redirect::to("login")->withSuccess('Great! You have Successfully loggedin');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `mass assignment` for save data you can use `YourModelName::create(data)`.but you should pay attention to 2 thing .

first one define all fillable fields that you want allow to assign mass in your model class.so you should add your imageName field in `fillable` array .

second you should append yourImageName to your `data` that assign mass.like :`data['yourImageField']=setvalue`.

But if you want to assign row by row(its more safe and better i think) you should do like this: `modelObject->Imagefield="imageName"` and at end `modelObject->save()`.